# Symmetric version of product and quotient differentiation rules

Tags: calculus, reference-request

The usual way of writing the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) and the [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) in differentiation is
$$(fg)'=f'g+fg'$$
$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'=\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}\quad\text{where}\quad g\ne 0$$

A few years ago, during a mathematics conference I attended in the Philippines, a foreign speaker presented a "more symmetric" way of writing these rules.  Unfortunately, I have forgotten what he wrote and an internet search did not yield it.

I've been playing around and I've found the following "nicer" presentation:
$$(fg)'=fg\left(\frac{f'}{f}+\frac{g'}{g}\right)\quad\text{where}\quad f,g\ne 0$$
$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'=\frac{f}{g}\left(\frac{f'}{f}-\frac{g'}{g}\right)\quad\text{where}\quad f,g\ne 0$$

I don't know if this is the version I saw a few years ago, but I'm pretty sure I'm not the first to think of this.

> What textbooks or lecture notes do you know that use this form for the product rule and the quotient rule in differentiation?

*Edit*:  As was pointed out in the comments, the "symmetric" version only works when $f$ and $g$ are nonzero, so it is not exactly the same as the "original" version.

Comment: I don't know, but I like this form!

Comment: Would this not be a better fit for [**HSM**](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @BenjaminDickman, many of my questions involve history of mathematics education, so it is a little hard to determine where I should ask them.  Let's see what the Mathematics Educators community feels about it.

Comment: I've changed the question so that it focuses more on education and not on history.  (Although the edit did make the question broader.)

Comment: I don't know where to find this, but, I see logarithmic differentiation in those formulas.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook I agree.  I just derived them from logarithmic differentiation.  Quite satisfying.  One thing I worry about is the sign of the functions (which might make taking log of them problematic).  Come to think of it, I am not sure how we are "usually" supposed to defend against such domain issues (other than, perhaps, and appeal to analyticity).

Comment: The symmetries are appealing, but these formulations don't have the same domain as the originals if $f$ or $g$ vanish.

Comment: @Adam, I agree that the difference in domain must be pointed out.  I will edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: Personally I just teach my students to rewrite $f/g$ as $fg^{-1}$ and then use the product rule. When students memorize a complicated formula of any kind, there is very little chance that they'll retain it a month after the final exam.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm pretty sure I've seen these formulations in some 19th century calculus texts.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, if you find a reference, please include it as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Just to elaborate on James Cook's observation in the comments, here is how to obtain these formulas using logarithmic differentiation.  I have made the post CW since it does not really answer the question.

$
\begin{align*}
P(x) &= f(x)g(x)\\
\log(P(x)) &= \log(f(x))+\log(g(x))\\
\frac{d}{dx} \log(P(x)) &= \frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x))+\frac{d}{dx}\log(g(x))\\
\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)} &= \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\\
P'(x) &= P(x)(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)})\\
\frac{dP}{dx} &= f(x)g(x)(\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)})\\
\end{align*}
$

The quotient rule is derived similarly.

I have not thought about logarithmic differentiation in a while.  I am a little worried about domain issues.  I guess just wrapping the initial equation in absolute value signs resolve these, but this still does not cover zeros of $f$ and $g$.

Actually, zeros are one reason to avoid this form.  For example, the usual product rule applies just as well to $f(x)=0$, $g(x) = \sin(x)$, while the modified form does not.

Comment: I would go further and say: the rules cited by Joel *are* logarithmic differentiation.  And they hold whether the factors are positive, negative, or complex.  (Just not zero.)

Comment: I recall that in Feynman's problem solving tips he recommended using logarithmic differentiation (though he didn't call it like that) when differentiating products of multiple functions. I guess having a more symmetric form helps, and the result is a bit more simplified.

Comment: I've never seen this before +1

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

I've been going through my papers and have found the source of the idea.  Roger Eggleton presented it in a talk at the *Severino V. Gervacio Conference on Graph Theory and Combinatorics 2009* held in Manila, Philippines from April 24, 2009 to April 25, 2009.

Aside from the two equations in the original post, he also presented the two equations below:
$$\frac{(fg)''}{fg}=\frac{f''}{f}+\frac{g''}{g}+2\frac{f'g'}{fg}$$
$$\frac{(f/g)''}{f/g}=\frac{f''}{f}-\frac{g''}{g}-2\left(\frac{f'}{f}-\frac{g'}{g}\right)\frac{g'}{g}$$

It seems the original reference for this is:

> Roger Eggleton and Vladimir Kustov, "[The Product and Quotient Rules Revisited](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Eggleton-CMJ-2011.pdf),"  *The College Mathematics Journal*, Volume 42, Number 4, September 2011, pp. 323-326.

Comment: The abstract of the article I cite is "*Mathematical elegance is illustrated by strikingly parallel versions of the product and quotient rules of basic calculus, with some applications. Corresponding rules for second derivatives are given: the product rule is familiar, but the quotient rule is less so.*"

Comment: I note that Eggleton and Kustov's result seems to have been published more than two years after they presented it, which seems pretty long in this case.

Comment: These formulas are natural modifications of the higher-derivative product rule, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule